# Checking for empty string before inserting the record

Tags: c#

I am custom importing some rows from a text file to our database and so I have bunch of codes like this for many fields.

```
 address.State = row["Location  State"].ToString();
```

I just noticed a requirement that says

> don't overwrite those fields in the value that we are reading from the
>   text file is empty or blank.

So I assume I can wrap them all around a check like this?

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpth(row["Location  State"].ToString()))
 address.State = row["Location  State"].ToString();
```

But before I go ahead and apply this kind of logic around all those fields I wanted to check and see if you have better solutions?

Comment: "So I assume I can write and copy paste a ternary if statement around all those assignments on the right to check for blank or empty"  Go ahead and try it.  You're going to struggle.  Assigning a value is a statement, not an expression.  The conditional operator expects two expressions, not two statements, unlike the `if` construct.

Comment: The ternary statement will work if you set each to itself when row value is empty

Comment: yes sorry bad terminology...I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an extension method could help here:

```
public static string ColumnValueOrDefault(this DataRow row, string column, string defaultValue)
{
    if (row == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("row");
    }

    if (column == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
    }

    if (defaultValue == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("defaultValue");
    }

    var rowString = row[column].ToString();

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowString) ? defaultValue : rowString;
}

Address.State = row.ColumnValueOrDefault("column", Address.State);
```

Comment: That extension gives the impression that you are setting the Address.State value to a boolean value... I would consider renaming that extension method to something like row.CollumnValue("collumnName", sCurrentVal);

Comment: The name was kind of random.. But I accept your comment. Changed it

Comment: sweet. I like this answer over mine, it is much more readable

Answer (score 1):

I would (and do) use this pattern personally :

```
string sTester = string.Empty

Address.State = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTester = row["collumn"].ToString()) == false ? sTester : Address.State;
```

This allows each collumn value to be set once, and the reused using the same string variable, and is relatively readable

Comment: I think that comparison bool value with `false` or `true` is not good idea. Maybe using `!` (not) operator is cleaner solution.

Comment: I use false to make the comparison more readable. Using the exclamation mark as a shortcut is easily over-read when coming back to view code. Is there a reason why comparing bool to bool is not a good idea? it seems perfectly logical to me.. It is not a nullable type by default, therefor it will have one of two static values, True, or False, making that comparison type safe and retaining readability

Comment: @idlerboris, as another question, why does an operator that accomplishes the same goal through practically the exact methodology qualify one coding style as cleaner than another? I do agree that this is a valid alternative, but not really relevant to the question nor the intent of the answer in relation to the question.

Comment: My comment didn't have relation to the question, of course. Comment was only about comparison bool value. I later thought that this discuss may generate holivar. Therefore, I think that it is bad idea to continue debate about this (at the more so comments of this answer is not suitable place for it)